# Where is the logic error in my if and if/else statements?

Tags: if-statement

```
if age < 20 then agecat=1;  
else if age < 50 then agecat=2;
else if age ge 50 then agecat=3;
else if age=. then agecat=9;
```

I can't figure out where the logic error is or how to fix it.  The only thing I can think of is a data validation line to make sure that, although the age variable is less than 20, that it's not a negative number.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what input do you set age, what agecat are you expecting and what agecat do you get?

Comment: You might also want to set parenthesis to avoid the [dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem.

Comment: what does the `ge` in `if age ge 50 then agecat=3;` means?